# Website unavailable after scaling down on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I experienced something weird today with my web app published on Azure App Services. I'm running on a "S3 Standard" app service plan and wanted to scale down to "S2 Standard" since the large VM isn't fully utilized. After switching to S3, my website where immediately unavailable.

I have scaled websites before without any problems and I just tested this on another account without similar errors. I know that it's kind of a wild shot here, but did anyone experience something similar?

UPDATE: I tried scaling down again. It gave a 502 for a couple of minutes, but then everything worked as it should.

Comment: Yeah I've had the same occur. Scaling vertically can take the app down for a moment.

Comment: @juunas this was 10 minutes until I switched back to the large plan. Then it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, different App Service plan tiers have different compute resources and features. For example, S3 Standard has 4 Core and 7GB RAM, but S2 Standard has 2 Core and 3.5GB RAM. You said the web site will be unavailable after you scale down App Service plan tier, but it works again if you reset to S3 Standard. Please make sure whether Azure Website has reached a resource quota limit and check whether CPU Percentage and Memory Percentage of your current App Service plan are very high.

Comment: I have configured scale out up to three instances, why high CPU usage should just result in a new instance being allocated, right?