# Poor performance on Azure web apps when scaling out

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm experiencing poor on Azure web apps when scaling out. Azure automatically picks up an issue from a set of rules I have set up (like CPU > 80% for 5 minutes). Then it increases the number of VMs by 1. Here is a screenshot of the settings on Azure:

[image: Azure app service scale settings]

This part works fine. But while it is scaling to one additional VM, I'm experiencing poor performance on the entire website. When the new VM is up and running, everything seems to work as expected.

I have previously observed similar issues when [scaling up and down the VM size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911258/website-unavailable-after-scaling-down-on-azure) but this is "just" a new VM.

I have already tried to create application initialization in my `Web.config`:

```xml
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
  <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

Still poor performance while scaling out. Does anyone know what this could be caused by? I wouldn't expect a website to perform worse while scaling. I know that the performance probably isn't that great when the VM reaches 80% CPU. But the performance is definitely worse as soon as Azure starts scaling.

Comment: I am observing high CPU usage (80%!) during around the upscaling activity... I suspect the upscaling is the cause...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly ensure that the margin between the scale out\in are not small. I have seen cases where the auto scale flapping was the issue.

To avoid a "flapping" situation, where scale-in and scale-out actions continually go back and forth. It is recommended to choose an adequate margin between the scale-out and in thresholds.

Just a adding a few best practices guide for you to review the metric threshold.

Ensure the maximum and minimum values are different and have an adequate margin between them - E.g- If you have a setting that has minimum=2, maximum=2 and the current instance count is 2, no scale action can occur. Keep an adequate margin between the maximum and minimum instance counts, which are inclusive. Autoscale always scales between these limits.

Always use a scale-out and scale-in rule combination that performs an increase and decrease - If you use only one part of the combination, autoscale will only take action in a single direction (scale out, or in) until it reaches the maximum, or minimum instance counts of defined in the profile. 
This is not optimal, ideally you want your resource to scale up at times of high usage to ensure availability. Similarly, at times of low usage you want your resource to scale down, so you can realize cost savings. I suggest you review the threshold for the metrics and example outlined in this documentation [Autoscale best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-best-practices#autoscale-best-practices), and let us know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post with a screenshot of the app service scale settings. It looks like all the requirements from your answer have already been taken care of.